# Why is Python datetime time delta not found?

Tags: python, timedelta, python-datetime

I am trying to make an array of dates in mmddyyyy format. The dates will start on the current day and then go two weeks into the future. So it all depends on the starting date. When I run my code I get an error that states:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "timeTest.py", line 8, in <module>
day = datetime.timedelta(days=i)
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'
```

I am not sure why this is happening because after searching online, I noticed that people are using the 'timedelta' in this way.

Here is my code:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta

dayDates = []
today = datetime.now()
dayDates.append(today.strftime("%m%d%Y"))
for i in range(0,14):
    day = today + datetime.timedelta(days=i)
    print day
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
import time
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta

dayDates = []
today = datetime.now()
dayDates.append(today.strftime("%m%d%Y"))
for i in range(0,14):
    day = today + datetime.timedelta(days=i)
    print day
```

The error that you are getting says, that `datetime` has no attribute `timedelta`. It happens, because you have imported from `datetime` specific things. In order to access `timedelta` now you type `timedelta` instead of `datetime.timedelta`.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta

dayDates = []
today = datetime.now()
dayDates.append(today.strftime("%m%d%Y"))
for i in range(0,14):
    day = today + timedelta(days=i)
    print day
```

Like that, your code should work properly. Also, pay closer attention to the error messages and try to read them carefully. If you focus enough, you often can sort out the problem basing on them on your own.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer!

Answer (score 4):

You already imported `timedelta`. You don't need to access it through datetime.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta

dayDates = []
today = datetime.now()
dayDates.append(today.strftime("%m%d%Y"))
for i in range(0,14):
    day = today + timedelta(days=i)
    print day
```

Answer (score 3):

The method you want to call is `datetime.timedelta`, as seen [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).  `datetime` is the module containing `timedelta`.

If you look at your `import` line:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta
```

...you'll see you're importing the `datetime` ***class*** from the `datetime` module.  So, when you call `datetime.timedelta`, you're actually calling `datetime.datetime.timedelta`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't know who wrote the `datetime` module but it was silly of them to create a `datetime` object within that same module