# Get the previous and next day from resultant date = datetime.strftime(datetime.utcnow(), "%Y-%m-%d")

Tags: python-3.x

date = datetime.strftime(datetime.utcnow(), "%Y-%m-%d")
Above date is returning the current date (Format as 2018-12-17). I want to get the previous day from this date. Can you please help me out on the same.

I have used date = date - datetime.timedelta(days=1) but getting the following error:
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37980802/7676971. Try `date = date - timedelta(days=1)`

Answer (score 0):

You most likely use `from datetime import datetime` and try to access `timedelta` from the `datetime` class and not the `datetime` module.
Change your import to `from datetime import datetime, timedelta`

Also your `date` variable is a string, you cannot substract a timedelta from it, use `datetime.utcnow()` instead.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> date = datetime.strftime(datetime.utcnow(), "%Y-%m-%d")
>>> date
'2018-12-17'
>>> yesterday = datetime.strftime(datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=1), "%Y-%m-%d")
>>> yesterday
'2018-12-16'
```